# How to cross reference two tables that have FirstName + LastName fields

Tags: sql, t-sql

I want to match two tables that both have first + last name fields. I would like to return the records that match each person's first + last name combination.

Table 1 fields:

```
id|firstname|lastname|position|
```

Table 2 fields:

```
firstname|lastname|datehired|department|deptcode|
```

Comment: If you are able, please consider adding a `PersonID` to the second table and removing the first and last name fields.  It will be much safer and cleaner to join them.

Comment: I would love to, but i asked my supervisor and they told me that was not an option, i had to match on names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join on multiple columns:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.firstname, t1.lastname, t1.position, 
       t2.datehired, t2.department, t2.deptcode
FROM Table1 t1 INNER JOIN Table2 t2
    ON t1.firstname = t2.firstname
   AND t1.lastname  = t2.lastname
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
Select FirstName, LastName From Table1

Intersect

Select Firstname, LastName From Table2
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include both conditions in your join

```
SELECT *  
FROM Table1  
JOIN Table2 ON Table1.firstname = Table2.firstname AND Table1.lastname = Table2.lastname
```